# How would I get the value of a counter! from the metrics crate in rust

Tags: rust, rust-metrics

I'm building a rust app for the first time. I want logging / metrics, but to confirm in testing that the function is behaving properly, I'd like to not just emit metrics using the [`metrics`](https://docs.rs/metrics/latest/metrics/) crate, I'd also like to retrieve the current value of the [`counter!`](https://docs.rs/metrics/latest/metrics/macro.counter.html).

It's unclear to me how to do this from the documentation, how would I get the value of a [`counter!`](https://docs.rs/metrics/latest/metrics/macro.counter.html) created with the metrics crate? I do not want any reporters at this stage if possible, I'm just looking to retrieve the value of the integer at that named place.

Comment: You can't, that might be intentional or an oversight on their part, maybe create an issue on their [github repositories issue tracker](https://github.com/metrics-rs/metrics/issues).